# Strange "on" type being recorded in MySQL database (Navicat Premium) in Django

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I have been trying to insert information with an HTML form into my database. However, when I submit, my "gender" and my "website_rating" has been strangely replaced with "on", when it is supposed to be replaced with my website input.

Image of the Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/94d8L.png

Here is my models.py

```html
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_  
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

"""
Quick Guide to Model Fields that We Did Not Use:

    - models.ForeignKey()
    - models.DateTimeField()
    - models.IntegerField()
    - models.IPAddressField()
    - models.FileField()
    - models.ImageField()
"""

# Create your models here.

class PersonalInfoResponse(models.Model):
    # Personal Info Section
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, default="N/A", verbose_name=u"Name")
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u"Age", default="N/A", null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, default="N/A", verbose_name=u"text#@thing.com")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, verbose_name=u"gender")

    # Website Response Section
    website_rating = models.CharField(max_length=3, verbose_name=u"1-10", null=True)
    heardof_flag = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u"truefalse", null=True)
    heardof = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name=u"How did you know about the C&C Education Center?")

    # Misc Section
    fav_subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, default="None", verbose_name=u"truefalse")
    fav_website = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default="N/A", verbose_name=u"What is your favorite part about this website?")
    website_improve = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default="N/A", verbose_name=u"What is something that this website needs improvement on?")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"User Contact Info"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

And here is my views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import PersonalInfoResponse

# Special Pages

def AfterSubmission(request):
    return render(request, 'html/elements/temp.html')

# Create your views here.

def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'html/index.html')

def Contact(request):
    # all_messages = PersonalInfoResponse.objects.all()
    # for message in all_messages:
    #     print(message.name)
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        name = str(request.POST.get('name', ''))
        age = int(request.POST.get('age', ''))
        email = str(request.POST.get('email', ''))
        gender = request.POST.get('gender', '')
        website_rating = request.POST.get('rscale', '')
        heardof_flag = request.POST.get('ynw', '')
        heardof = str(request.POST.get('heardof_res', ''))
        fav_subject = str(request.POST.get('subjects', ''))
        fav_website = str(request.POST.get('fav_part', ''))
        website_improve = str(request.POST.get('improve_part', ''))

        # Saves User Input
        usermessage = PersonalInfoResponse()

        usermessage.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else 0
        usermessage.age = age if isinstance(age, int) else 0
        usermessage.email = email if isinstance(email, str) else 0
        usermessage.gender = gender 
        usermessage.website_rating = website_rating
        usermessage.heardof_flag = (1 if heardof_flag == 'Yes' else 0)
        usermessage.heardof = heardof
        usermessage.fav_subject = fav_subject
        usermessage.fav_website = fav_website
        usermessage.website_improve = website_improve

        usermessage.save()
    return render(request, 'html/contactform.html')

def About(request):
    return render(request, 'html/about.html')

# Elements folder

def Register(request):
    return render(request, 'html/elements/register.html')

def Login(request):
    return render(request, 'html/elements/login.html')

def Classes(request):
    return render(request, 'html/elements/classes.html')
```

The "gender" and "website_rating" are both HTML radio inputs. Here is the section of my HTML code:

```html
Gender:<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required"> Female 
<input type="radio" name="gender" required="required"> Other

<br><br>
                
On a scale of 1~10, how do you rate this website?<br> 
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 1
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 2
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 3
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 4
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 5
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 6
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 7
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 8
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 9
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required"> 10
```

I have no idea what is going on. Can somebody help me?

*This is my first question on StackOverFlow, if I am missing anything feel free to criticize me.*

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are missing `value`s, so as per the HTML spec, you get `"on"`, since the radio button is selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="rscale" required="required" value="2"> 2
```

etc...

Also, please look into [Django's Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) and [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead of doing `request.POST` things by hand.

Thirdly, if a rating is a number, make it so:

```
website_rating = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u"1-10", null=True)
```

If it's required, make it non-nullable.

```
website_rating = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u"1-10")
```